# Operator overloading in Kotlin and how does this code work?

Tags: kotlin

I am reading the following code from a tutorial but I don't really get it. Basically it tries to use operator overloading so that the following code works:

```
return today + YEAR * 2 + WEEK * 3 + DAY * 5
```

What I understand:
This part:

```
operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval): MyDate {   
    return addTimeIntervals(timeInterval, 1)  
}
```

Enhances the class `MyDate` to support the `+` with a `timeInterval` so this would work `myDate + YEAR` for example.

This part:

```
operator fun MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: RepeatedTimeInterval) 
    = addTimeIntervals(timeIntervals.timeInterval, timeIntervals.number)
```

Enhances the class `MyDate` to support `*` with a `RepeatedInterval`

This part just declares an empty class with 2 member variables `timeInterval` and `number`

```
class RepeatedTimeInterval(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val number: Int)
```

What I don't understand is how the multiplication is actually happening, since `RepeatedInterval` is just an empty class. How can I understand this?

```
import TimeInterval.*  

data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int)  

enum class TimeInterval { DAY, WEEK, YEAR }  

operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval): MyDate {  
    return addTimeIntervals(timeInterval, 1)  
}  

class RepeatedTimeInterval(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val number: Int)    
operator fun TimeInterval.times(number: Int) = RepeatedTimeInterval(this,   number)  



operator fun MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: RepeatedTimeInterval)   
    = addTimeIntervals(timeIntervals.timeInterval, timeIntervals.number)  




fun task1(today: MyDate): MyDate {    
    return today + YEAR + WEEK  
}  
  
fun task2(today: MyDate): MyDate {   
    return today + YEAR * 2 + WEEK * 3 + DAY * 5   
}
```

Also this is part of the tutorial:

```
import java.util.Calendar  

fun MyDate.addTimeIntervals(timeInterval: TimeInterval, number: Int): MyDate {   
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()  
    c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth)  
    when (timeInterval) {  
        TimeInterval.DAY -> c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, number)  
        TimeInterval.WEEK -> c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, number)  
        TimeInterval.YEAR -> c.add(Calendar.YEAR, number)  
    }  
    return MyDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),   c.get(Calendar.DATE))  
}
```

Comment: The multiplication happens in `operator fun TimeInterval.times(number: Int) = RepeatedTimeInterval(this,   number)`

Comment: Thanks for `MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: RepeatedTimeInterval)` (as well as `MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YEAR * 2` is `TimeInterval * Int`. The compiler sees it isn't a built-in combination, so it looks for a method `times` marked as `operator` on `TimeInterval` which accepts `Int` (so e.g. `TimeInterval.times(Int)` or `TimeInterval.times(Any)`). This method can be a member of `TimeInterval` or an extension; there's absolutely no reason for it to be a member of `RepeatedTimeInterval`.

In fact, `RepeatedTimeInterval` doesn't have any part in resolving `YEAR * 2` at all, it just happens to be the return type. Then `today + YEAR * 2` is `MyDate + RepeatedTimeInterval` and the same rule is applied to pick `operator fun MyDate.plus(timeIntervals: RepeatedTimeInterval)` (and not `operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval)` which is used for `today + YEAR`).

Note that with this code it isn't legal to have e.g. `YEAR * 2 * 2`; *that* would require `RepeatedTimeInterval.times(Int)` which again could be a member or an extension.

Comment: I updated the post with that method. But I still don't get what's going on

Comment: Then (unless I misunderstand which part you don't get) you'll need to look at `GregorianCalendar.add` source, which is kind of complex.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the class `RepeatedTimeInterval` is an empty class and the operator `TimeInterval.times` is not part of it. So how does this part work. Is my question clearer?

Comment: Ok, then my initial answer was irrelevant. I've changed it.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. `In fact, RepeatedTimeInterval... just happens to be the return type and then the compiler chooses the overload of MyDate.plus according to that. ` I didn't understand this part. My undestanding is that `RepeatedTimeInterval` is an empty class with 2 member variable similar to `Pair<TimeInterval,Int>`. How is it related to `MyDate`? Sorry new to Kotlin

Comment: It's only related through a method available on `MyDate`. See the edited paragraph.

Comment: Ah I see. `RepeatedTimeInterval` then is some kind of mock class to make this work right? Is this kind of class really needed? Seems weird as someone new to Kotlin to create such an empty class to solve this problem

Comment: Not mock class, as you say above it's basically `Pair<TimeInterval, Int>` (and that could be used instead).

Comment: So `today + YEAR * 2 ` becomes `today.plus(TimeInterval.times(2))` and that is `today.plus((YEAR, 2))` which becomes `addTimeIntervals(YEAR,2)`. But isn't a `plus(MyDate)` which is the return type of `addTimeIntervals` needed? How is the `today` get added?

Comment: `today` doesn't get added to anything, you don't have `<something> + today`. Things get added to `today`, which needs `MyDate.plus`, not `plus(MyDate)`.

Comment: Yes we have ` today + YEAR * 2 ` which is `today.plus(RepeatedTimeInterval(YEAR, 2))`  right? So this code works only for today's date? Otherwise I don't see how could something like `tomorrow.plus(RepeatedTimeInterval(YEAR, 2))` would give the correct date

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is how the multiplication is actually happening, since `RepeatedInterval` is just an empty class. How can I understand this?

Well, the **RepeatedTimeInterval class** is indeed "an empty class", but notice that it has an extension function **TimeInterval.times(number: Int)** which makes it support the operation TimeInterval * Int, for example: YEAR * 2

I came across this program while doing the [Kotlin Koans: Operators overloading task](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Conventions/Operators%20overloading/Task.kt), here's my solution:

```
import TimeInterval.*

data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int)
// Supported intervals that might be added to dates:
enum class TimeInterval { DAY, WEEK, YEAR }

class MultipleTimeInterval(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val amont : Int)
operator fun TimeInterval.times(amont: Int) = MultipleTimeInterval (this, amont)

operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval): MyDate = addTimeIntervals(timeInterval, 1)
operator fun MyDate.plus(multi: MultipleTimeInterval): MyDate = addTimeIntervals(multi.timeInterval, multi.amont)

fun task1(today: MyDate): MyDate {
    return today + YEAR + WEEK
}

fun task2(today: MyDate): MyDate {
    return today + YEAR * 2 + WEEK * 3 + DAY * 5
}
```

The utility function MyDate.addTimeIntervals() is:

```
import java.util.Calendar

fun MyDate.addTimeIntervals(timeInterval: TimeInterval, amount: Int): MyDate {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.set(year + if (timeInterval == TimeInterval.YEAR) amount else 0, month, dayOfMonth)
    var timeInMillis = c.timeInMillis
    val millisecondsInADay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L
    timeInMillis += amount * when (timeInterval) {
        TimeInterval.DAY -> millisecondsInADay
        TimeInterval.WEEK -> 7 * millisecondsInADay
        TimeInterval.YEAR -> 0L
    }
    val result = Calendar.getInstance()
    result.timeInMillis = timeInMillis
    return MyDate(result.get(Calendar.YEAR), result.get(Calendar.MONTH), result.get(Calendar.DATE))
}
```