# Tutorial on operator overloading in Kotlin- why `import TimeInterval.*`

Tags: kotlin, import

I am totally new to Kotlin. I was trying to understand the question and answer at [Operator overloading in Kotlin and how does this code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858489/operator-overloading-in-kotlin-and-how-does-this-code-work). I could not understand the line `import TimeInterval.*`. I tried googling for such a package/class, but could not find any.
The code goes on to declare `enum class TimeInterval{DAY, WEEK, YEAR}` three lines later, and the subsequent code appears to refer to this class. So why is the `import` necessary?

Comment: Good question!  I don't think the `import` *is* necessary, if all that is going into one file.  I suspect it actually came from multiple `.kt` files (in which case the `import` _would_ be needed), and the author pasted them all together without change.

Comment: @gidds That would be correct for `import TimeInterval`. But for `import TimeInterval.*` as in the question Andrei's answer gives the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, you have to write `TimeInterval.YEAR + TimeInterval.WEEK` and so on instead of `YEAR + WEEK`